# this. Get( "object. Value") not working properly in ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

Sometimes this.get("object.value") not working properly in ember.js. But this.get("object").value is working. Any reason?

```js
this.get("object").value = "values"   // WORKS ✅
this.get("object.value") = undefined // DOESN'T WORK
```

Answer (score 3):

Can you clarify "what isn't working"? what do you expect to happen? what does your data look like?

is `object.value` accidentally a key with a dot in it?
For example:

```
{
  'object1.value': 1,
  // vs
  object2: {
    value: 2
  }
}
```

get with `object1.value` *won't work* because there is no key named `object1`
But `object2.value` will work because there is a key named `object2`

so, if you want to access properties with `.` in the key, you'll need a custom method that does that (likely with square bracket access).

for example:

```js
import { get } from '@ember/object';

function customGet(obj, keyOrPropertyPath) {
  if (keyOrPropertyPath in obj) return obj[keyOrPropertyPath];

  return get(obj, keyOrPropertyPath);
}
```